# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=n\ln\left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx}\right)$ at $(0,\infty)$.

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let us first study the pointwise convergence of the sequence $ f_n $. For this we will consider the following limit, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln \left( \dfrac{1+nx}{nx} \right )=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\ln \left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx} \right )}{\dfrac{1}{n}}. $$ Applying the L'Hospital rule $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\ln \left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx} \right )}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{nx+1}=\dfrac{1}{x+1/n}=\dfrac{1}{x}.$$ Therefore $f_n\to \dfrac{1}{x}$ pointwise when $n\to \infty$ at $(0,\infty)$.

Now, for each $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x>0$, define $A_n$ \begin{align*}
        A_n&:=\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\{|f(x)-f_n(x)|\}\\
        &=\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left \{\dfrac{\left |1-nx\ln\left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx} \right)\right |}{|x|}  \right \}\\
        &\ge \sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left \{\dfrac{|1-nx\ln(1+nx)}{|x|} \right \}\\
        &\ge \sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left \{\dfrac{|1-nx\ln(2)}{|x|} \right \}\\
        &\ge \sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left \{\dfrac{|1-x\ln(2)|}{|x|} \right \}\\
        &=\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left \{\left |\dfrac{1}{x}-\ln(2) \right | \right \}\to \ln(2),x\to\infty.
    \end{align*}

So $ A_n \ge \ln (2) $. Thus, $ f_n $ does not converge uniformly. Is my try right ?

Comment: I am totally convinced that those inequalities are incorrect. Also the last sup is not $\log 2$. Think about what happens when $x$ is close to $0$. Instead you can say $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} \left| {\frac{{1 - nx\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{nx}}} \right)}}{x}} \right| \ge \left| {\frac{{1 - n(1/n)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{n(1/n)}}} \right)}}{{1/n}}} \right| = \left| {1 - \log 2} \right|n.
$$

Comment: And $ | 1- \ln (2) | n $ does not tend to $ 0 $ when $ n \ to \ infty $, that way there is no uniform convergence. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You see, the usual trick to disprove uniform convergence is to choose a specific value of $x$ in terms of $n$. In this particular problem, $x=1/n$ suffices. By the definition of sup, the sup is at least as large as the expression evaluated at a specific point.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. For the trick too, I didn't know :).